Does Hades 2 have Perfect Catches?
In the first Hades, there were certain rare fish you could only catch with a Perfect Catch, which required reacting to a catch in under .34 seconds. Does this same Perfect Catch mechanic exist in Hades II?

No, fishing has changed in Hades 2.
In this game, in order to fish, you have to quickly press the reel button while the lure is within a small circle, representing the sweet spot where the fish is located.
Some fish are harder to catch, and will have more circles. The fish's rariry it's not time-related.

You have to hit the button in that sweet spot several times in order to reel in your catch. How many times you have succeeded is indicated by small blue circles at the bottom of the screen.

The first few catches are still one-press catches like in Hades 1. I got my first multi-press catch after this question was asked.
